# jQuery css animation shaking when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

[image]

I have this outer div, contains a table.
What I want is when I horizontally scroll the outer div, the header of the table stay fixed. I have sussessfully did this by create a new table that contains only the header, this divheader is absolute position left: 0;

When the outer div scroll, left position of divheader equals outer div scrollLeft.

```
$('#outerDiv').scroll(function () {
    var left = $('#outerDiv').scrollLeft();
    $('#divheader').css('left', left);                
});
```

This work pretty well on firefox, but on chrome, divheader shaking sometimes, when scrolling fast. On IE(10), it shakes all the times.

My questions is how can I avoid the shaking things on IE and chrome.

Please consider this fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7xZm/11/. Test it on IE

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Comment: @Shashank I've already added the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `left` property on `scroll()`, why not set the `#divheader` position to `fixed`.

See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7xZm/1/).

---

EDIT:

It can't find any technique to prevent that shaking/jerky `#divheader` on `scroll()` better than just setting it a `position:fixed`. So instead I made a solution to enable scrolling down on that fixed element:

First we need to wrap `#divheader` table on a `<div>` and we'll set its `scrollTop()` position base on the `#outerDiv`'s `scrollTop()` value.

```
$('#outerDiv').scroll(function() {
    var top = $('#outerDiv').scrollTop();
    $('#headerWrapper').scrollTop(top);    
});
```

Then we'll need to set the `height` of this wrapper equals to the height of the `#outerDiv` so it won't overflow on it. Getting the height of `#outerDiv` is a little tricky because of the scrollbar. And the best solution I've come up with is getting the `height` of element which is set to `100%` inside the `#outerDiv`.

```
//create a new element with height 100% inside the '#outerDiv'
var p = $('<p style="height: 100%;"/>');
$('#outerDiv').append(p);
//get the elements height then remove it
var h = p.height();
$(p).remove();
//set the wrapper's height
$('#headerWrapper').height(h);
```

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7xZm/14/).

Comment: I wish I could. problem is I have a limited height for outer div, and sometimes I have to scroll down when the table is long

Comment: yes I see. I've updated my answer, I think there is nothing smoother than setting `position:fixed` so instead I made a solution for you to able to scroll down on this fixed element as well.

Comment: Great, thanks to you now I fixed the problems. I created a wrapper to wrap it. And in stead of changing left position of the table, now I change the margin-left. Thanks a lot Mark!